# Filling large flooring gaps with rigid material

Tags: flooring, crack, epoxy

I have a couple of flooring transitions that have approx. 1/2" wide and deep gaps between dissimilar covering materials. I would like to fill them with something that is both rigid (so not foam or caulking) and that can accept small trim nails because I would like to install some thresholds or quarter-round. Is there a material (2-part epoxy?) that I could squeeze out of a tube into the void that, when it solidifies, can hold a nail?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Those aren't "cracks". A crack is damage to something where it's split or released. These are gaps, voids, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You appear to have one edge that's tapered, and one edge that's uneven.  Depending what your substrate is, your best bet is probably to cut the edges of the hardwood even and parallel to the other floor material, and fill with suitable wood.  You might try matching the hardwood color (difficult), or leaning in and using a contrasting color.